# Google Developer Console - duplicate OAuth Client IDs being automatically generated?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-console

I have an Android application that uses Google APIs (Drive API, Drive SDK, G+ API) which is currently working properly.

Within the Google Developer Console I originally created two 'Client ID' OAuth Credentials one for production and one for debug/development. I recently logged in and noticed there are now 17 Client IDs. 16 of which use the same SHA1 value used for my production/published instance (the Client ID values are all different.)

How and why were the other 15 Client IDs created (I am the only developer with access)? Can I delete some of these.. if so which ones? And finally what 'tag' on SO represents the Google Developers Console?

Comment: I've added a tag for the Google Developers Console (google-api-console). I haven't heard any reports of this happening before, nor am I aware of any reasons that extra client IDs would be generated. I would hesitate from deleting them, as there may be unforeseen consequences.

Comment: Eric, are you aware of a limit to the number of Client IDs for each Project?

Comment: I've seen some mentions of a limit, but I'm not certain if one exists.

Comment: I thought a limit of 20 was mentioned somewhere in the api documentation but can't seem to find it now. If 20 is the number then I'm close to hitting that wall. Any advice from Google? How can I determine which ClientIDs the various published versions are using?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to determine which client IDs are in use. I have also heard of a 20 limit, but can't confirm.